# Unable to create an EKS Cluster with an existing security group using Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-eks

I'm having issues when trying to create an EKS cluster with a few security groups that I already have created. I don't want a new SG every time I create a new EKS Cluster.

I have a problem with a part of this code under vpc_id part."cluster_create_security_group=false" produces an error, and cluster_security_group_id = "sg-123" is completely ignored.

My code is like this:

```
provider "aws" {
  region = "us-east-2"
}

terraform {
  backend "s3" {
    bucket = "mys3bucket"
    key    = "eks/terraform.tfstate"
    region = "us-east-2"
  }
}

data "aws_eks_cluster" "cluster" {
  name = module.eks.cluster_id
}

data "aws_eks_cluster_auth" "cluster" {
  name = module.eks.cluster_id
}

provider "kubernetes" {
  host                   = data.aws_eks_cluster.cluster.endpoint
  cluster_ca_certificate = base64decode(data.aws_eks_cluster.cluster.certificate_authority.0.data)
  token                  = data.aws_eks_cluster_auth.cluster.token
}

variable "cluster_security_group_id" {
  description = "Existing security group ID to be attached to the cluster. Required if `create_cluster_security_group` = `false`"
  type        = string
  default     = "sg-1234"
}

module "eks" {
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/eks/aws"
  version = "~> 18.0"

  cluster_name    = "cluster-example"
  cluster_version = "1.21" #This may vary depending on the purpose of the cluster

  cluster_endpoint_private_access = true
  cluster_endpoint_public_access  = true

  cluster_addons = {
    coredns = {
      resolve_conflicts = "OVERWRITE"
    }
    kube-proxy = {}
    vpc-cni = {
      resolve_conflicts = "OVERWRITE"
    }
  }

  vpc_id     = "vpc-12345"
  subnet_ids = ["subnet-123", "subnet-456", "subnet-789"]
  create_cluster_security_group=false ----------> ERROR: An argument named "cluster_create_security_group" is not expected here

  cluster_security_group_id = "my-security-group-id"

  # EKS Managed Node Group(s)
  eks_managed_node_group_defaults = {
    disk_size      = 50
    instance_types = ["t3.medium"]
  }

  eks_managed_node_groups = {
    Test-Nodegroup = {
      min_size     = 2
      max_size     = 5
      desired_size = 2

      instance_types = ["t3.large"]
      capacity_type  = "SPOT"
    }
  }


  tags = {
    Environment = "dev"
    Terraform   = "true"
  }
}
```

Where am I wrong? This is my whole Terraform file.

Comment: I think it's `create_cluster_security_group` not `cluster_create_security_group`: https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-eks/blob/master/variables.tf#L221-L225.

Comment: Interesting. It did solve that error, but my cluster was still created with a new SG, not the one that I specified.. @MarkoE

Comment: I also think there should be `cluster_security_group_ids`, which is a list of subnet IDs. Because in this line https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-eks/blob/master/main.tf#L24 it adds them all to the cluster.

Comment: So that means I must create VPC_Config variable? If it's a var at all?
``` security_group_ids      = compact(distinct(concat(var.cluster_additional_security_group_ids, [local.cluster_security_group_id])))``` is a bit confusing to me, should I put my sg's here or in another place? @MarkoE

Comment: You would need to add your SGs when calling the module, i.e., just add the `cluster_security_group_ids` to the `module "eks"` block. Also, I am not the one that has written the module, so it's almost as new to me as it is to you. :)

Comment: Thanks a bunch, will try and give u the results!

Comment: Hi, this adds a SG but now blocks nodegroups from creating.. Any ideas why? @MarkoE

Comment: Can you update the code block with the changes?

Comment: Yes, I have now @MarkoE

Comment: The issue is - Upon creating nodegroup, it fails to create nodes, and the nodegroup ends up in 'failed to create' state after some point

Comment: Ok, have you tried adding this variable `cluster_security_group_ids` and assigning it **all** the security groups you want?

Comment: No, will do it now @MarkoE

Comment: Hey MarkoE, new update.. I added it, but now I get new error upon creating.. I will leave an error here:
```
waiting for Security Group (sg-123) Rule (sgrule-123) create: couldn't find resource
│ 
│   with module.eks.aws_security_group_rule.node["egress_cluster_443"],
│   on .terraform/modules/eks/node_groups.tf line 170, in resource "aws_security_group_rule" "node":
│  170: resource "aws_security_group_rule" "node" {
```